# How does jasmine-jquery simulate HTML fixtures?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'd like to know if there is anything underlying jasmine-jquery like a browser engine or something that it uses to simulate HTML stuff?

Of is it just a self written DOM Model? Is it even a DOM Model?

The reason for that question is that i need to know how reliable tests are written with this fixtures. Can they / should they be used with a whole application loaded into the fixtures for unit testing the application?

How can they be compared to the behaviour of different browsers? So does it behave more like Chrome, Firefox, or even IE6 or is it a custom implementation of the W3C Standards?

Unfortunately i wasn't able to find anything about this. Maybe it's to obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Karma project. It runs your jasmine tests in real browsers, so you don't have to worry about it.
 I'm not sure what engine jasmine uses to power its DOM, but you are better running your front end tests in real browsers.

For node script, use jasmine_node.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr: The fixtures are simply appended into a **div with an id of jasmine-fixtures** as defined in the **jasmine.Fixtures constructor**.

You can check for yourself:

```
fit("See fixtures",function(){
    setFixtures("<h1 id='ahoy'>Hello World</h1>");
    expect($("#ahoy")).toExist();
    alert($("html").html());
});
```

In your jasmine.jquery.js dependency the code is really clean and easy to follow, check the following methods - *Fixtures,addToContainer_,createContainer_*

As a sidenote - we currently successfully adopted Jasmine which allows us to follow TDD in a front-end ES5 + jQuery project I am working on. It is a very similar experience to what the test setup of the *create-react-app* ships with.